# Pig in local mode on a large file

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I am running pig in local mode on a large file 54 GB. I observe it spawning lot of map tasks sequentially . What I am expecting is that maybe each map task is reading 64 MB worth of lines. So if I want to optimize this and maybe reads 1GB equivalent number of lines,

a.) Is it possible?(Maybe by increasing split size)
b.) How?
c.) IS there any other optimum approach.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase split size by setting:

```
SET mapred.max.split.size  #bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

By default block size is 64MB.
Try this to increase the block size:

Open the hdfs-site.xml file. This file is usually found in the conf/ folder of the Hadoop installation directory.Set the following property in hdfs-site.xml:

```
-property- 
-name-dfs.block.size-name- 
-value-134217728-value- 
-description-Block size-description- 
-property-
```

Comment: Its pig on local mode.. so there no hdfs-site.xml